# Making a sencha touch app work offline?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I've tried using the download from the sencha website

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Taking_Sencha_Touch_Apps_Offline

when uploaded to my server and viewed on my ipad offline the app just says you need to be connected to the internet or words to that effect. Any ideas how to fix this or does anybody have a working offline example?

Comment: What happens if you load the same app in Google Chrome (with the Developer Tools open)? Does the console show any error or caching event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly related to the point, but you could take a look at PhoneGap (http://www.phonegap.com/) if you're looking for a more complete offline solution, at the price of a higher complexity and app store issues.
I found it quite well done and it offers a greater flexibility wrt offline storage and native access.